# Programmatically check for a motion jpeg image on Android

Tags: android, jpeg

I have a method for shrinking large images on Android, but it is getting choked up when the user either selects a motion JPEG from the device or they use the camera with motion enabled.

I've looked at the exif data for a motion image on file, with exiftool and I see the attributes with values:

```
MicroVideo
MicroVideoVersion
MicroVideoVersionOffset
```

but I do not see these in the EXIF data within Android using the ExifInterface.  I peeked at all the mAttributes and they are not there.

Is there an easy way of identifying these images and possibly extracting the jpeg from the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I learned a lot more than I ever wanted to know about jpeg images.  The motion values I was looking for were not in the exif section, they are XMP meta properties stored in another section.

To programmatically view this section, there are a few libraries that can do it, I used the Adobe XMP Core library.  It is one of few that allows writing the header as well.

To extract only the jpg image from a motion enabled file, similar to the Extract menu item in Google photos, it can be done with the following code, utilizing the XMPUtil class found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/3574026/src/com/android/camera/util/XmpUtil.java).  All the code does is read the XMP header and grab the offset.  Then it copies only the jpeg section in to a new file, then removes the XMP values.

```
        val xmp = XmpUtil()
        val meta = xmp.extractOrCreateXMPMeta(photoFile.absolutePath)

        val haveVideoValue: XMPProperty? = meta.getProperty("http://ns.google.com/photos/1.0/camera/", "MicroVideo")

        val haveVideo = haveVideoValue?.value == "1"

        if (haveVideo) {

            val offsetValue = meta.getProperty("http://ns.google.com/photos/1.0/camera/", "MicroVideoOffset")

            meta.deleteProperty("http://ns.google.com/photos/1.0/camera/", "MicroVideo")
            meta.deleteProperty("http://ns.google.com/photos/1.0/camera/", "MicroVideoOffset")
            meta.deleteProperty("http://ns.google.com/photos/1.0/camera/", "MicroVideoVersion")
            meta.deleteProperty("http://ns.google.com/photos/1.0/camera/", "MicroVideoPresentationTimestampUs")

            val copyBytes = photoFile.length() - offsetValue.value.toLong()

            val tmpImageWithoutVideo = createTmpFile(photoFile.name)

            FileInputStream (photoFile).use { inputStream ->
                FileOutputStream(tmpImageWithoutVideo).use { outputStream ->
                    IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream, 0, copyBytes)
                }
            }

            photoFile.delete()

            // Remove the XMP Motion values
            val newImageFile = createTempFile(photoFile.name)

            FileInputStream(tmpImageWithoutVideo).use { inputStream ->
                FileOutputStream(newImageFile).use { outputStream ->
                    xmp.writeXMPMeta(inputStream, outputStream, meta)
                }
            }

            tmpImageWithoutVideo.delete()

            photoFile = newImageFile
        }
```

This is a [nice page](https://android.jlelse.eu/working-with-motion-photos-da0aa49b50c) that helped me out.